# Add alternative smtp to mail configuration

Tags: java, android, email

I am using commons apache jar to send mail. In that i have set smtpport as 587, but since it is blocked my few ISPs, my mails are not delivered. Can i add some sort of alternative port along with 587 so that if 587 is not working, alternative can be used like port 26

```
email.setSSLOnConnect(true); 
email.isStartTLSEnabled(); 
email.setSmtpPort(587);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add alternavtive port 306. And do you set auth for it?

Comment: That is what i want to know. Syntax to add alternative port and condition to check when first port is blocked, use port second. i added auth.

Comment: You can try: `try - catch(MessagingException e)`. In `catch` body, you call create session with port 306. So, if port 587 not working, your application will run create session you write in `catch`.

Comment: this means if that port also does not work, i have to redo same with another port and this way i can put all available ports as alternative. If this is the only way, it is very crude.

Comment: At port no exception is thrown if it fails to send mail then how we can use try and catch. There is nothing to catch. Can you suggest how to check available ports instead